# JSON_decode two dimensional array of objects?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I have a two dimensional array of objects like so:

```
function test(n){
  this.id = n;
}

var testArray= new Array(2);
for(i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){
  testArray[i] = new Array(2);
  for(j = 0; j < testArray[i].length; j++){
    testArray[i][j] = new test((2*i)+j);
  }
}
```

I then stringify it to post using AJAX like so:

```
var data = {testA: {testB: testArray[0], testC: testArray[1]}}
var text = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Once I perform the jquery AJAX call:

```
$.post("test.php",text,function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

I cannot work out how to decode and use this object on the PHP side, so far i've tried something like this:

```
<?php 

$data = json_decode($_POST);
if($data == null){
    echo "fail";
} else {
    echo $data; 
} 

?>
```

But I get an error that says it expects a string and I'm passing it an array. I've also tried something like

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['testA']);
```

and then error doesn't appear but instead it always outputs "fail".

Does anyone know what I need to do on the PHP side so I access the data?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you run stringify on it? If you just send it like this:

```
$.post("test.php", data, function(data) {
```

You should be able to retrieve it like this:

```
$data = $_POST['testA'];
```

Comment: I just tried posting the data directly and when i call

   $data = json_decode($_POST['testA']);

I get an error still where it says its expecting a string

Comment: There is no json_decode in my answer, because this way, $_POST['testA'] is already an array.

Comment: Ah my mistake, ok it works now. Thank you very much :) I understand that I don't need to stringify the data as i'm already putting it in JSON format manually myself. So I was stringifying a JSON object before?

Comment: No, you're not using JSON at all now, because it's not necessary.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now. I got confused about what I needed to do to transfer the data across and thought JSON was required. I guess that's where I got confused.